# How do I to send an specific link in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to write a code that allows me to send an specific link within an array. This is a short idea of what I'm trying to do. Depending on the country code I'll send a brochure in the specific language. I also want to know if I can do it by switch...

This is the code I got so far...

```
<?php
$de_brochure = ('https://ruta/de-brochure.pdf');
$en_brochure = ('https://ruta/en-brochure.pdf');
$es_brochure = ('https://ruta/es-brochure.pdf');
$country_code = 'ES'; // Normally I get this code from a form.
$brochure = array ( $de_brochure, $en_brochure, $es_brochure );
$brochure_link = '';

if ( $country_code == 'ES' ) {
    $to = 'info@kazzabe.com.es';
    $subject = 'Ejemplo';
    $txt = 'El dossier a enviar es' . $brochure_link[$brochure];
    $headers = 'De: sample@sample.com' . '\r\n' .
'CC: anothersample@sample.com';
    mail ($to, $subject, $txt, $headers );
} else {
    echo $country_code . 'no es el código de españa';
}
```

When I run my code, this is the output I GET:

**WARNING Illegal offset type on line number 17**

**NOTICE Uninitialized string offset: 1 on line number 17**

Comment: Well, `$brochure_link` is a string, not an array, so `$brochure_link[$brochure]` will raise an error.

Comment: what you expect ? there is no array `$brochure_link` with index `$brochure_link[$brochure]`

Comment: If I knew how to do it I thin I won't be asking @Rishi Thanks for being so polite. That was just an idea and I want help to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You make your array and a unused "link" variable

```
$brochure = array ( $de_brochure, $en_brochure, $es_brochure );
$brochure_link = '';
```

And then access this link variable instead of the array:

```
$txt = 'El dossier a enviar es' . $brochure_link[$brochure];
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is where it fails. Using an array with named keys (a.k.a. hash) would make it easier:

```
$brochures = [
    'DE' => 'https://ruta/de-brochure.pdf',
    'EN' => 'https://ruta/en-brochure.pdf',
    'ES' => 'https://ruta/es-brochure.pdf'
];

$country_code = 'ES';

# ...

$txt = 'El dossier a enviar es' . $brochures[$country_code];
```

Comment: Thank you @sidyll I'll make those fixes and try to run it again to see how it goes. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! I used this code as explained and it worked very well. Thanks a lot! @sidyll

Comment: Happy to help @KAZZABE !

Answer (score 0):

do something like this

```
$brochure_link_arr= array(
"DE"=>'https://ruta/de-brochure.pdf',
"EN" =>'https://ruta/en-brochure.pdf',
"ES"=> 'https://ruta/es-brochure.pdf'
);

if ( $country_code == 'ES' ) {
..
$txt = 'El dossier a enviar es' . $brochure_link_arr[$country_code];
```